# Android Update SSL Certificate

Tags: android, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I am building an Android Application which consumes a REST Api through an HTTPS connection. Right now to ensure the connection to this api I am using a file cert embedded in the app as explained in this [example](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#UnknownCa), at Android Documentation.

It is working well, but recently the certificate has changed and I had to publish the Application again with the new cert file.

My question is: What is the best way to avoid this everytime the certificate changes? How to do it without using a cert file embedded directly in the app?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the objective of having the SSL certificate? Is this a self-signed certificate? Are you implementing certificate pinning?

Comment: I did this implementation because without it I was havng the following error:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

I have not much knowledge about ssl certifcates and this is managed by an external entity. Is there any questions I should do to them?

I thing it is a self signed certificate.

Thanks!

Comment: Check the domain your app is connecting to using an online SSL scanner such as https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html. It will let you know if it is using a self-signed certificate or a valid one issued by a certificate authority.

Comment: You are doing what you need to do, give or take. In the ideal situation, you would (1) pin the site's public key, (2) the site operator would practice key continuity and (3) the site operator would not change the key. We found key continuity to be a very desirable security property, especially in the web security model where interception is a valid use case. You could supply the third party site certificate used by the app out-of-band. That is, have your app contact your server (which practices continuity) to fetch the third party's site certificate. You would pin the public key to your site.

Comment: Thanks to all! It was a problem in the configuration of the certificate missing some intermediate certificates. They fixed it and now there is no need to have the SSL certificate in the app as @CommonsWare mentioned.

Thanks to all again!